# Is there a solution for this recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $a_n=\begin{cases}
\frac{n+1}{3}, & n\equiv 2 \pmod 3 \\
a_{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\rfloor}, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$ for all integer $n\geq1$, where $a_0=0$.

Is there a closed form for $a_n$?

Thank in advances.

Comment: Have you tried making a table of values to see what you get?

Comment: yes I have tried.

Comment: It is tied into the location of $2$'s in the base $3$ expansion of $n+1$, but I haven't found a rule

Comment: Note the standard use of (1) alignment tabs, (2) \text{}, and (3) \pmod, within "cases", as in my edit. $\qquad$

Comment: it seems that everything is 0 except n=3(2+3k) and n=3(2+3k)+1 which are mapped to ((n+1)/3+1)/3 and usually the terminal condition n=3k+2 wih is (n+1)/3

Comment: table of value for $a_n$ cpp.sh/2zdzp (Click Run)

Comment: @Bless floor divide n consecutively by 3, if the result is 2 then this is mapped to 2, or if the number gone ever accross while dividing is writte as 3k+2 then result is k, otherwise result is 0

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt figure out any getaround except this :

Write the number as:

$$3^n\delta_n+3^{n-1}\delta_{n-1}+...\delta_0$$ where all $\delta$'s $<3$

Make a walk from $\delta_0$ to $\delta_n$

If any $\delta$ crossed through = 2 the result is what is behind otherwise it is 0

It does mean, if $\delta_k=2$ then the result is $3^{n-k-1}\delta_n+....+\delta_{k+1}$